# Enabling component manager in gcloud CLI

Tags: kubernetes, gcloud, kubectl, google-cloud-platform

I made a fresh install of gcloud for ubuntu as instructed [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/). I want to use the additional components offered by gcloud like **kubectl** and **docker**.

So, when I tried typing `gcloud components install kubectl`, I get an error saying that **The component manager is disabled for this installation**. Here is the full error message:

[image: gcloud component install error]

Answer (score 9):

This is because you installed `google-cloud-sdk` with a package manager like `apt-get` or `yum`.

**kubectl**: 
If you look [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/downloads#apt-get) you can see how to install additional components. Basically `sudo apt-get install kubectl`.

If by **docker** you mean the `docker-credential-gcr` then I don't know if there's a way to install using a package manager, can't seem to find it. Perhaps ou can try the [github repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/docker-credential-gcr).  Mind you, you don't need this for commands like `gcloud docker -- push gcr.io/your-project/your-image:version`.
*If you mean actual docker for building images and running them locally, that's standalone software which you need to install separately, [instructions here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/).*

Alternatively, you can uninstall `google-cloud-sdk` with `apt-get` and then reinstall with [interactive installer](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/downloads#interactive), which will support the suggested `gcloud components install *`

Comment: Great answer! I just wanted to share a little bit of the motivation behind why the component manager is disabled in this manner. It turns out that software distributions don't like you shipping a mini-package manager inside of their package manager. This makes things like uninstallation nearly impossible, so they request that we disable the component manager when shipping the Cloud SDK.

Comment: Looks like right now apt-get is the recommended install method (https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-debian-ubuntu) for Ubuntu/Debian.